# How to convert html into docx using interop in C# along with embedded images?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt, interop

So basically what I want to do is I want to convert a HTML file into docx but along with images. 
Currently, I am able to do this but if I send this file to someone else the images will not be displayed as the images are currently using my local system path.
Here is the code I am doing right now.

```
       // Load the file to transform.
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

        using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(xmlPath, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
        {
            document.Load(fileReader);
        }

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(htmlPath, xslTransform.OutputSettings);

        xslTransform.Transform(document, writer);
        writer.Close();

        wordDoc = wordApplication.Documents.Open(FileName: htmlPath, ReadOnly: false);
        wordDoc.SaveAs2(FileName: docPath, FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);

        wordDoc.Close();
```

Can anyone please help me with this? It would be great help thanks.

Comment: Are the images a Base 64 string or Binary.  You cannot use StreamReader with binary it will corrupt the images.  You need to read binary either using Binary Reader or File.ReadAllBytes().

Comment: @jdweng I have xml and xsl file. Basically the xml file having links. So currently I am converting it into html using xslTransform. But that html consists of images absolute path. Is there any way to get image url in xml into base64 url while converting it into html with the help of xsl.

Comment: Do you want the binary in the xml or just the URL.